# Migration to spring boot give a noSuchMethodError with junit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I migrated to spring boot 3.2.1. (from 3). I use java 21 and gradle 8.5

Only test i have

```
@SpringBootTest
class AcmetWebApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

I get this error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> 'org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExecutableInvoker
> org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getExecutableInvoker()'

Edit

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.2.1'
        springCloudAzureVersion = '5.8.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
          url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = '21'
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory'
        implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory-b2c'
        implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    }
    
    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-dependencies:${springCloudAzureVersion}"
        }
    }

    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
    
}

subprojects {

    project(':acme-extranet-web') {
        jar {
            enabled = false
        }

    }
    
    project(':acme-intranet-web') {
        jar {
            enabled = false
        }
    }
    
    project(':acme-public-web') {
        jar {
            enabled = false
        }
    }
    
}

    }
    
    project(':acme-public-web') {
        jar {
            enabled = false
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I think you also have to update the `jUnit` version. TO be sure and to provide a answer, can you share your `pom.xml` file or `build.gradle` file  as update of the question?

Comment: it's done, i have updated

Comment: can you check `gradle dependencies` maybe there are version difference in project I guess ?

Comment: It is harder to tell you something about the dependencies when you're not using fixed version numbers as everyone should. Never the less make sure JUnit 5 (jupiter) is updated as well and that you have not mixed up junit 4 and 5 annotations within the same test. Runner might be 5 but internal 4 which make it break the same. JUnit 5 always has "jupiter" in path

Comment: it's spring boot who manage dependencies